# Selecting all Events, along with extra column "attending"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `Events` table, and I have an `Attendees` table where I maintain the `event_id` and `user_id`.

I am trying to select all events, along with an additional column "attending" which I want to be the boolean result of whether the current user is attending that particular Event.

Here's the query that I am trying which seems to return the right result (against my basic test suite), and I am wondering if there is anything wrong with this or a better way.

Assuming the user who requested is user_id = 18..

```
SELECT events.id,
       EXISTS(SELECT 1 from attendees WHERE user_id = 18 AND event_id = events.id) AS "attending"
FROM events;
```

Results in:

```
| id       | attending      |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | false          |
| 2        | true           |
| 7        | true           |
```

Comment: Why not using a JOIN? That's most straight forward and works like a charm. By the way, the query above can't work. Could you show us your real SQL?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the query.  Been working on a "pinned items" and I typed that accidentally.  My apologies!

Comment: When you say with a JOIN, how would that work for getting the true/false value?  I've been using joins to get additional details, for example to get the user details joining the user_id on users.id.   Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, I am not a pro or expert at database, but I used Exists after reading https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-exists/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT events.id,
       event_id IS NOT NULL AS "attending"
FROM events
    LEFT JOIN attendees ON event_id = events.id AND user_id = 18;
```

And make sure you have indexes on user_id, event_id and events.id, to get performance.

Edit: Query is still a bit strange because it gets all events, and only checks for user_id 18 if he/she has been attending.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know that you can use joins in this way.  I am curious - when should I use exists then?  Or always prefer to use a JOIN when I want to use exists (and there are 2 table) ?

Comment: My first choice is a JOIN, but sometimes I take another tool and EXISTS() might be used. There no right or wrong